# How to make scp copy hidden files?

Tags: scp, files

I often use SCP to copy files around - particularly web-related files. The problem is that whenever I do this, I can't get my command to copy hidden files (eg, .htaccess).

I typically invoke this:

```
scp -rp src/ user@server:dest/
```

This doesn't copy hidden files. I don't want to have to invoke this again (by doing something like `scp -rp src/.* ...` - and that has strange `.` and `..` implications anyway.

I didn't see anything in the `scp` man page about an "include hidden files".

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I assume that `src/.*` also copies `src/..` (the parent directory), right?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

That should absolutely match hidden files. The / at the end of the source says "every file under this directory". Nevertheless, testing and research bear you out. This is stupid behavior.

The "[answer](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/moving-home-data-from-old-system-to-new-linux-system.html)" is to append a dot to the end of the source:

`scp -rp src/. user@server:dest/`

The **real** answer is to use rsync.

Comment: Nice trick I did not realized this yet.

Comment: rsync -avz -e ssh --progress src/ user@server:dest/

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior.  `scp -r source/ host:source2` copies dot files.  Works in OpenSSH 5.1 from 2007.

Comment: Note that adding a `.` at the end no longer works (2019) due to security issues.  This is explained here:  https://superuser.com/questions/1403473/scp-error-unexpected-filename

Comment: `scp: error: unexpected filename: .`

Answer (score 31):

You can try rsync. It's better suited for this job:

> rsync -av src/ user@server:dest/

(And its manual page is worth reading.)

Comment: I _always_ use the --progress option for rsync, I can't live without it =D

Comment: @Hofa I usually use -P because it is shorter, already includes --progress and also includes --partial which can make sense if I am already interested in its progress ;-)

Comment: Use this if you need different port :
rsync -av -e "ssh -p 2222" src/ user@server:dest/

Answer (score 10):

Don't put a slash after the source directory. Your code would look like this:

```
scp -rp src user@server:dest/
```

This will create a directory 'src' under 'dest' on the remote machine, with all the hidden files included. It's probably not exactly what you want, but it will copy hidden files in src.

Comment: This will copy `src` to `user@server:dest/`, not contents of this directory.

Comment: Totally agree and I think my answer said that. It will make a copy of `src` (and all its content) underneath `dest/` on the destination server. It will not put a copy of all the things inside `src` directly under `dest`.

Answer (score 7):

To copy only hidden files, Use this command

```
scp -rp /path_to_copy_hidden/.[!.]* user@host:/path_to_paste/
```

Actual game is the `/.[!.]*` tag that is referring to files starting with `.`(hidden)

Comment: this should be accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

The following will solve the problem, this has been fully tested on our continuous integration environment

```
scp -rp src/ user@server:dest/
example scp -rp /usr/src/code/ content001@172.11.11.11:/usr/dest/code/
```

Hope it helps

Comment: After updating scp recently, this now results in `scp: error: unexpected filename: .
`. Make sure to test whether it works with your distribution, fellow Googler :)

Comment: The command as they posted it did work in the past. A patch for vulnerability [CVE-2018-20685](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-20685), which you can view the contents of [here](https://github.com/openbsd/src/commit/4667d15cf6214d4cb6b8c347f13864ca8c72002e), has left this functionality broken for the past few years. That being said, it's rather rude to imply someone didn't do their research at the time of posting an answer, especially an upvoted one. Things change over the course of years. No reason to be disrespectful about it.

Comment: I have fixed it now, apologies for the inconvenience might have caused to you because of this @MoritzFriedrich

Answer (score 1):

As `scp` supports regular expressions, this will nicely do the trick for you:

`scp -rp src/(*|.*) user@server:dest/`

Answer (score 0):

None of the above scp solutions worked for me.
However, I did find that the following worked on cygwin:
scp -r directory/* host:directory
The '*' matched all visible files and skipped the invisible.

Answer (score 0):

If password login is disabled on the remote machine, and the only way to login is via public key, then you can use this:

```
$ rsync -av -s 'ssh -i /path/to/your/private/SSH/key' --progress user1@remote.host:/remote/source/directory/ /local/destination/directory/
```

It copies hidden files too.

Also please note that "user1" must have the permissions to read those files, for example you can't copy other user's ssh folders with this method.

Answer (score -1):

## Distributed revision control handles hidden files

Because of the CVE-2018-20685 vulnerability, the `/.` trick [can no longer be used](https://superuser.com/a/1403506/219226) with `scp`.
However, distributed revision control like `git` or Hg Mecurial **will handle hidden files like any other files.** Here are the commands for my favourite [Hg Mercurial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial):

```
server:$ sudo apt install mercurial
client:$ sudo apt install mercurial
client:$ hg init src
client:$ cd src/
client:$ hg addr
client:$ hg com -m "first commit"
client:$ cd
client:$ hg clone src ssh://user@server/dest/
```

Subsequent changes will need to be committed again with `client:$ hg com -m "commit message"` and then pushed using the `client:$ hg push` command. Learn more about pushing changes from this [Hg Mercurial cheat sheet](https://hamwaves.com/hg-mercurial/en/index.html).